# Create a search filter based on custom variable product field

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, custom-fields

I'm trying to find out how to create a custom search filter for WooCommerce products.
I have added 2 custom fields to the product variations: `_min_height` and `_max_height`. I set the min and max height fields for example to 1000 and 3500.

I need to build a custom search filter where the user can fill-in min and max height and then he filters products by the values in `_min_height` and `_max_height`.

I hope you can help me out with this! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ddb for fixing the typos in my question. It's my first.

Comment: An advice to get better helped: Try to find some useful code on here (or over internet) concerning a custom search on WooCommerce *(variable)* products. There is a lot of people with similar problems… Then Update your question with this code (and the link reference, if possible). This way you get a base to get helped and it shows that you are trying to solve your request.